# how can I fix a not working software updater on ubuntu 18.4?

Tags: ubuntu, python3, software-updates

When I select the software updater , the icon for the application appears and then disappears.

when I try to run it via terminal, I am getting this error:

```
 sudo update-manager -C
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/update-manager", line 28, in <module>
    import gi
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/__init__.py", line 42, in <module>
    from . import _gi
ImportError: cannot import name '_gi' from partially initialized module 'gi' (most likely due to a circular import) (/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/__init__.py)
```

It should be noted that I upgrade my python3 to 3.8.0.

Could it be the problem?

How can I fix it?

Comment: Yes. Updating may be the reason. I just run several versions of Python depending on which versions are needed by software I use.

Comment: @svin83 how can I fix it? How to install different versions of python on ubuntu in a way that it does not break it?